# How to use image_picker in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am confused about how to use image_picker, this is how I use it in my application (like in many tutorials):

```
class AddDialogState extends State<AddDialog> {
    File galleryFile;
    Widget _onlyStatus() {
         getLocalImage() async {
               var _galleryFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
                     source: ImageSource.gallery
               };
               setState(() {
                   galleryFile = _galleryFile;
               });
               print(_galleryFile.path);
         }

         return Column(
               ........
               FlatButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                         getLocalImage();
                    }
               )
         )

    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         // fullscreen dialog
         .........
         body: _onlyStatus()
    }
}
```

The problem was, the above code doesn't start ImagePicker, when i click the FlatButton, the above code just produce an error `the getter 'path' was called on null`, it doesn't start any new activity related to gallery, so what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is there a gallery application on your test device? I assume that you are using Android since you talked about an activity. For iOS, additional setup is required.

Comment: Yes, MIUI Gallery

Comment: Have you tried to look into the [example app](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/example/lib/main.dart)? You may find there what you actually need.

Comment: [Flutter ImagePicker examples](https://androidride.com/image-picker-flutter-take-picture/)

Answer (score 3):

[image: flutter imagepicker- pickimage deprecated.]

Actually pickImage() is deprecated now. So you have to use ImagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)

[Click here for more](https://androidride.com/flutter-notes-taking-app-tutorial/)

```
void getImage(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    PickedFile imageFile = await picker.getImage(source: imageSource);
    if (imageFile == null) return;
    File tmpFile = File(imageFile.path);
    final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final fileName = basename(imageFile.path);
    tmpFile = await tmpFile.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
    setState(() {
      _image = tmpFile;
    
    });
  }
```

The code also store image file in device directory. Path pacakage is also used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example you only need to call the SelectionItem and pass the required parameters and it's done, also it includes support for Android and iOS.

```
class SelectionItem {
  String text;
  GestureTapCallback action;

  SelectionItem({
    this.text,
    this.action,
  });
}

Widget _getOptionWidget(SelectionItem item) {
  return SimpleDialogOption(
    onPressed: item.action,
    child: Text(item.text),
  );
}

Widget _getCupertinoOptionWidget(SelectionItem item) {
  return CupertinoActionSheetAction(
    onPressed: item.action,
    child: Text(item.text),
  );
}

showSelector(
  BuildContext context, {
  String title,
  List<SelectionItem> actions,
}) {
  bool isAndroid = Injector.instance.platform == Platform.ANDROID;

  if (isAndroid) {
    final items = actions.map((action) => _getOptionWidget(action)).toList();
    return SimpleDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      children: items,
    );
  } else {
    final items =
        actions.map((action) => _getCupertinoOptionWidget(action)).toList();

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        CupertinoActionSheet(
          title: Text(title),
          actions: items,
          cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            onPressed: () {
              NavigationUtils.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text("Cancel"),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but where i must put SelectionItem, and what kind of action ?

Comment: you should create a showDialog with a button to go to the gallery on that button action you should call SelectionItem and it will display your gallery

Answer (score 0):

your showDialog should be something like this:

```
Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) => showSelector(
                      context,
                      "Select",
                      actions: [
                        SelectionItem(
                          "Camera",
                          action: () {
                            getImage(ImageSource.camera);
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        ),
                        SelectionItem(
                          "Gallery",
                          action: () {
                            getImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
```

Comment: I tried but ```Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found``` on showSelector -> actions -> SelectionItems

Comment: The problems was ImagePicker won't start any activity to pick an image, i add ```ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)``` to button, and when i click that button, then nothing happen, no new activity

Comment: Look, all you need include the showSelector code from my first response and later call the showSelector on the onTap() or onPress() action you wanna and should work flawlessly as my second response

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4 (flutter 2.8.1)

```
bool hasImage = false;
File? image;

Future getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
      if (image == null) return;
      final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
      setState(() {
        this.image = imageTemporary;
        hasImage = true;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Failed to pick image: $e');
    }
  }
```