# how to create an image picker from gallery and camera in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

i want to create a function in flutter to pick image from gallery and camera in my page. can someone help me with this code please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTiSE.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUgNV.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Productdetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const Productdetails({super.key});

  @override
  State<Productdetails> createState() => _ProductdetailsState();
}

class _ProductdetailsState extends State<Productdetails> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        title: const Text('Product List'),
        titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 22,
            wordSpacing: 2.5,
            color: Colors.black),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.save)),
        ],
      ),
      body: const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20,horizontal: 20),
      child: Text(
'Product Image',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check out the plugin [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) and [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)?

Comment: I have added the plugin in pubspec.yaml. the problem is I don't know the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use image\_picker in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762602/how-to-use-image-picker-in-flutter)

Comment: Check out their examples? They are well documented especially the camera.

Comment: i have done the camera and gallery button, but the image is shown below but i want the image to be shown in circle avatar, how can i do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you either the image_picker or file_picker package.

The image_picker has a future function that allows you to pick image from gallery or camera and it returns a file object. You can use the path to that file to set your image.

The file_picker allows you to pick any file from your storage either image, video etc. But you can put restrictions on it to select only images.

Comment: thanks i have did that, but how can i show the image in circle avatar, currently the image is shown below the camera and gallery buttons

Answer (score 0):

This is part of your State class in a Stateful widget:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

    class _SnapshotState extends State<Snapshot> {
      File? _imgFile;
    
      void takeSnapshot() async {
        final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
        final XFile? img = await picker.pickImage(
          source: ImageSource.camera, // alternatively, use ImageSource.gallery
          maxWidth: 400,
        );
        if (img == null) return;
        setState(() {
          _imgFile = File(img.path); // convert it to a Dart:io file
        });
      }
    }
```

Code snippet to display the image in an Avatar:

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 32,
  backgroundImage: (_imgFile == null)
  ? AssetImage('assets/person.png')
  : FileImage(_imgFile!) as ImageProvider,
)
```

In case image loading/clicking fails, you should have a dafault image in your project assets. Include it in your pubspec.yaml file.